# Going back to Thunderbird from Evolution

Tags: gnome, email, thunderbird, evolution

When trying to export my emails back to Thunderbird I get to the step where it says go to `/home/chris/.local/share/evolution/mail/local`.

But I don't see any files with no extention on them. Because if I read correctly, I am suppose to drag the files with no extension at the end to Thunderbird and then launch Thunderbird, and all my emails would be there.

But in `/home/chris/.local/share/evolution/mail/local` folder this is all I see:

> [image: screenshot]

How do I import the emails from Evolution?

Comment: Says where? What instructions are you following?

Comment: I used google... I just typed in Transferring Evolution to Thunderbird.